# About UIImageView with round corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I'm trying to make a UIImageView with round corners, so I used [imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f]; it works but not perfectly.

If you look closely, you can see the corners of the image(I uploaded a photo, I don't know if you can see it clearly, there are blue parts in the corners). How should I remove these? thank you.

(P.S.: I also set the border of the view, is that the reason why?)

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you showed the actual code where you set the corner radius because then the question I'm about to ask would already be answered: are you also setting masksToBounds for the layer to YES?

Comment: Yes I did. I set masksToBounds to yes

Comment: Have you applied any background color to imageView?

Comment: Yes,I set the background, but this image filled the whole imageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView` doesn't clip to bounds by default. So while the corner radius is applied its still drawing outside of its designated area.

objc:

```
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

swift:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```